# How to check 4 neighbor connectivity in grayscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
mat = 
  147  155  139  104   84  139
  136  134   99   73   60  144
   98   82   60   54   47  118
   86   59   46   48   38   90
   88   66   50   44   35   67
   88   75   53   40   43   48
p = mat(3,3)
q = mat(2,5)
V = [1:60]
```

all i want is to check if there exist a path between pixel p and q using vector V, for example given matrix above there exist a paths: path1: (3,3) , (3,4) , (3,5) , (2,5) path2: (3,3) , (4,3) , (4,4) , (4,5) , (3,5) , (2,5) and many other paths, Note: pixel value in each path's coordinate should be in 'V' and obviously p and q should also be in 'V'. that's what i am trying to achieve in MATLAB

Code i've written so far:

```
mat = 
  147  155  139  104   84  139
  136  134   99   73   60  144
   98   82   60   54   47  118
   86   59   46   48   38   90
   88   66   50   44   35   67
   88   75   53   40   43   48
p = mat(3,3)
q = mat(2,5)
V = [1:60]
% need to check N4 connectivity through pixel value p to q
cc = bwconncomp(mat,4)
for i=1:cc.NumObjects 
 pix = cc.PixelIdxList{i}
 if any(ismember(pix(:), p)) && any(ismember(pix(:), q)) && any(ismember(V(:), p)) && any(ismember(V(:), q))
   display('found N4 connectivity')
end
```

**Actual Question**: is this correct way to do the required task or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: sorry , i corrected the code check what i actually mean is initialize matrix with 1 to 60 subscripts.

Comment: yeah i've seen his problem , but it don't solve mine, and yes i've executed code on matlab it runs fine but don't display anything.